# Log/list of external/unauthorized programs that were given permission to open

Tags: applications, security, settings, logs

When an app/program is not from an authorized developer, it cannot be opened directly because of security settings.

These security settings can be overridden by adding the app as an exception to the security settings, or by using the "open anyway" button in the security & privacy settings page.

Where can I see a full list (with complete paths) of all apps/scripts that were ever added as security exceptions in this manner? I suspect a previously "allowed by me"/installed app to be dirty and need to check.

Comment: Start off by looking at `scutil --list` because that will list all the events that Gatekeeper encountered; both "allow" and "deny". Unfortunately, all the apps are hashed, so it will require some investigative work.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the tip. I actually found another nice place. I did a grep -iR for one of the names I recalled and one of the files it turned up in was: /Volumes/HDD1/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist This is a file with complete records with dates and names. SO happy to have found it, Apple normally hides all this *useful* info from users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a `grep -iR` for one of the names I recalled and one of the files it turned up in was: `/Volumes/HDD1/Library/Receipts/InstallHistory.plist`, HDD1 being the name of the drive the OS is installed on. So happy to have found it, because Apple increasingly hides all this *useful* info from users.

This is a file with complete records with names of all installed programs and the dates they were installed on and some other info.

Comment: Nice!  +1.   Simplicity!

Comment: Has anyone been able to determine whether it's possible to whitelist an app by manually adding it to this file?